# Free Flash Media Players

Tags: flash

I understand that both JW player and Flow player are OS, but they both have expensive licensing terms.

The only fully free player that I'm aware of, MPW_Player. Seems dead.

Are there any free players that are not dead? Or should I just bite the bullet and get a license?

Comment: The free version of Flow Player has no licensing restrictions, it just doesn't allow you to remove the flowplayer name from the player.  If you really needed to unbrand flowplayer for your site it's only $100.  Most companies drop $100 on appetizers at lunch so it doesn't really seem that expensive to me.

Comment: It's not really that expensive, still I would prefer not to pay if I can, as I don't really make money from my blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FPlayer](http://as3flvplayer.sourceforge.net/) is open source.

From the site:

> FPlayer :: Open Source AS3 FLV Player
>   Project
>
> FPlayer is an object oriented, open
>   source FLV Player Project, coded using
>   Adobe Actionscript 3.
>
> You can use FPlayer to show videos on
>   your web projects, develop it and
>   change its skin easily.
>
> With XML playlist option you can
>   arrange it for showing multiple
>   videos.
>
> FPlayer doesn’t use any components
>   unlike the other FLV players and it’s
>   only 8kb.
>
> FPlayer basicly includes a volume
>   control button, a video scrubber, and
>   full screen option.

Info on the upcoming version 3 is here: http://code.google.com/p/fplayer/

Answer (score 1):

[This NetTuts+ tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/how-to-play-video-using-an-open-source-player/) refers to [OS FLV](http://www.osflv.com/Demonstration.html) and [FLV Flash fullscreen](http://www.video-flash.de/flv-flash-fullscreen-video-player/) open source players besides the ones discussed here. It also describes the process with source code.

There is also a VLC reference on [this Wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX).